# How to get the specific row with View button

Tags: php

```
$database = new Connection();
                        $db = $database->open();
                        try{    
                            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM payroll_payment';
                            foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) { }

<br> Name: <b>  <?php echo $row['fullname'] ; ?> </b> </br>
                                        <br> Item Name: <b> <?php echo $row['item']; ?> </b> </br>
                                        <br> Item Price: <b> ₱<?php echo number_format($row['price'],2) ?>  </b></br>
                                        <br> quantity: <b> <?php echo $row['quantity']; ?> </b> </br>
                                        <br> Commission: <b> ₱<?php echo $row['commission']; ?>  </b> </br>
                                        <br> Date: <b>  <?php echo $row['date']; ?> </b>  </br>
                                        <br> Total Sale: <b>₱<?php echo number_format($row['totalsale'],2) ?> </b> </br>
                                        <br> Total Commission: <b> ₱<?php echo number_format($row['totalcommission'],2) ?> </b> </br>
                                        <br> Grand Total: <b> ₱<?php echo number_format($row['grandtotal'],2) ?> <b> </br>
```

within this code im getting the first row. i want to get the specific row for each user data. When clicking the view button i want to show each user data.

Comment: Your `foreach` is empty, place your html/output code inside the `{ }`

Comment: fyi, `</br>` doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect.
You first put everything in the loop.
Then can get all the lines.

Try what I wrote it should work for you great

```
<?php
$database = new Connection();
$db = $database->open();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM payroll_payment';                   
?>
<?php foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row): ?>

    <br> Name: <b>  <?= $row['fullname'] ; ?> </b> </br>
    <br> Item Name: <b> <?= $row['item']; ?> </b> </br>
    <br> Item Price: <b> ₱<?= number_format($row['price'],2) ?>  </b></br>
    <br> quantity: <b> <?= $row['quantity']; ?> </b> </br>
    <br> Commission: <b> ₱<?= $row['commission']; ?>  </b> </br>
    <br> Date: <b>  <?= $row['date']; ?> </b>  </br>
    <br> Total Sale: <b>₱<?= number_format($row['totalsale'],2) ?> </b> </br>
    <br> Total Commission: <b> ₱<?= number_format($row['totalcommission'],2) ?> </b> </br>
    <br> Grand Total: <b> ₱<?= number_format($row['grandtotal'],2) ?> <b> </br> 

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Thanks by the way. But i want to view the specific ID when clicking the button of view. i want to get each row per id. not whole data row.